# Wordpress HTACCESS 301 Redirect Querystring index.asp

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I have a basic WordPress HTACCESS. What I want to accomplish is a 301 Redirect from:

/index.asp?id=herhaalrecept_aanvragen-5

to

https://www.example.nl/aanmelden-nieuwe-patienten/

I tried many options with QUERYSTRING but no luck. I removed it from the example below because I think it is not even close.

Has anybody got an idea?

Tnx in advance

**Example of my HTACCESS now below:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php? [L]

Redirect 301 /index.asp?id=herhaalrecept_aanvragen-5 https://www.example.nl/aanmelden-nieuwe-patienten/

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` or `RewriteRule` doesn't match query string. You need `RewriteCond` for that also you must keep that rule before other WP rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=herhaalrecept_aanvragen-5(&|$)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.asp$ https://www.example.nl/aanmelden-nieuwe-patienten/? [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php? [L]
```